# conflicting scripts: image-slider malfunctions when i added fancyBox scripts to html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am redesigning a webpage that has an image slider on the top to show some of my featured work. The image-slider works fine and works by clicking the right or left arrow for the next or previous image.

All was well until I added the links to the fancyBox files so that other images (not in the slider) in that page could be viewed in the pop-up fancyBox.
fancyBox works fine, but because of it my slider now disappears once one clicks the left or right arrow.

**Can someone please help me fix the slider, or fancyBox, so that both the slider scripts and FancyBox work on this page?**

[Here is a link to the webpage](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/270523/help/layout/index.html)

In the source I have also noted which files in the  are part of the slider and which are for FancyBox

I would really appreciate any and all help!

Thanks in Advance,
theirf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are loading two different versions of jQuery. One in the header(1.7), the other is in the top of m.js(1.4.2). Try taking that copy of 1.4.2 out of m.js to start. Make sure to check your console for errors, then go from there.

Also, I'm not all that sure about the slider script you are using. I have used [BxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) with fancyBox on the same page before, and they play great together... Just an idea.

Comment: oh i didn't know that. I removed the 1.4.2 js from m.js, but that didn't seem to work. I'll take a look at BxSlider

Comment: so now you are loading jQuery after you are trying to run the m.js... Load jQuery first, and see if that causes the slider to work.

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work. I got BxSlider to work though. However, do you have any other suggestions on getting my custom slider working?

Answer (score 1):

See an error when stepping through in Firebug:

```
When I called show(slide,[object Object]) with your args, an error was thrown!
TypeError: f.easing[i.animatedProperties[this.prop]] is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

...e)});else for(var g in a)ca(g,a[g],c,e);return d.join("&").replace(bD,"+")}}),f....
```

Caused by `$("#pic-" + next).show('slide',{direction: dir});`

where 'dir' is an empty string. Believe this is causing your error.
You also have a few other issues...such as hiding before showing. Check out more jQuery anim stuff or..simpler use a pre-built slider :)

Comment: oh wow. well, i guess it was a mistake to use a custom slider because i have no idea on how to fix those errors.

And chrome gave me no errors in the console...(weird)...so i assumed there were none.

Do you have any suggestions on pre-built sliders?

Comment: Yeah, I love the jQuery Tools one www.jquerytools.org

Comment: Oh, and the comment below is true too...you have another version of jquery in m.js.

Comment: thank you for your help. yes, i removed that, but it sill didn't work.